# gnuplot from file with multiple metrics

Tags: c, gnuplot

I have a C program that writes three files with the first column being the X values (clock cycles). The other columns are a set of metrics like % of memory usage, memory "holes", etc. Like I said before, there are three files like this (one per algorithm: first fit, best fit and worst fit).

Example - Headers: Clock Cycle, % Memory Usage and Number of "holes":

File 1 (First Fit):

```
1 20% 5
2 30% 9
3 70% 12
4 90% 3
```

File 2 (Best Fit):

```
1 15% 3
2 20% 5
3 80% 7
4 40% 3
5 60% 9
```

File 3 (Worst Fit):

```
1 15% 3
2 20% 5
3 80% 7
```

I would like to know if there is a way with gnuplot to generate one graph per metric comparing the three algorithms in those metrics.

By the way, sorry about my english, hope you guys understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set term pngcairo size 600,400

set output 'memory.png'
plot 'file1' using 1:2 w lp, \
'file2' using 1:2 w lp, \
'file3' using 1:2 w lp

set output 'holes.png'
plot 'file1' using 1:3 w lp, \
'file2' using 1:3 w lp, \
'file3' using 1:3 w lp

.......
```

(it would be better if you get rid of '%' in second column)

Comment: The '%' is for demonstration only, there is no '%' in the real files. Thank You for answer, let me try.